# Next.JS "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am currently implementing useSWR in order to fetch data from my express and mongo-db backend. I am able to fetch the data successfully from the database no problem. The following is the code i used to achieve this:

````
```//SWR method for hydration
const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())
const { data, error } = useSWR('http://localhost:3000/appi/daily', fetcher)
if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>```
````

This is then accessed using:

`data.currentInfo.username`
where username is one of the fields in the collection.

The problem comes in when i try to add this information into a state hook, which then returns the error rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

Removing the line:
`const[displayNumber] = useState(data.currentInfo.randomString)`
and any line that uses the state variable displayNumber then fixes the error completely.

I have included the relevant code below:

```
    const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())
    const { data, error } = useSWR('http://localhost:3000/appi/daily', fetcher)
    if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
    if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
    
      
    const[displayNumber] = useState(data.currentInfo.randomString)


    //handler function for changing state variable
    function handleNumChange(event){
        console.log(event.target.value);
        setNumber(event.target.value);
      } 


    
    return(
      <div>
        <div>
            <Navbar className="navbar"/>
            <h2>{data.currentInfo.username}</h2>
            <h2>{displayNumber}</h2>
```

In short im pulling the data with swr, adding this information to a state variable and then displaying it with a h2.

Could anyone enlighten me what is possibly wrong with this approach?

I have searched online for the error which says that it could be caused by useEffect hooks but there isn't any in my code.

Comment: Move all your hooks to the top of the component and before the conditional rendering - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: Hi if i move the hooks to the top,

 const[displayNumber] = useState(data.currentInfo.randomString)
the above code will not work since data.currentInfo is not initalized yet

Comment: Yes, then you get an error, I saw that - you need to set the initial state of `displayNumber` with a fallback to a default value, i.e. `useState(data && data.currentInfo && data.currentInfo.randomString || null)`

Comment: Hi sir i just tried ur suggestion and i still got the same error
"Cannot access 'data' before initialization"

Comment: Right, do it exactly as suggested in the answer below but add that check in my previous comment.

Answer (score 7):

The error describes u have more hooks than previous render. If u read the react docs, all `useState` hooks should always be called every render. You can't have a conditional `useState` while your code has an extra `useState` bellow following:

```
if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
```

That means if there is no `error` and there is `data` only then the line `const[displayNumber] = useState(data.currentInfo.randomString)` will be called.

**EDIT:**
Move it to the top will normally resolve your issue.

```js
    const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())
    const { data, error } = useSWR('http://localhost:3000/appi/daily', fetcher)
    //const[displayNumber] = useState(data.currentInfo.randomString) //Needs null checks ofcourse
    //With null checks
    const[displayNumber] = useState((data && data.currentInfo && data.currentInfo.randomString) || undefined)
    //OR
    //const[displayNumber] = useState(data?.currentInfo?.randomString)
    if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
    if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
```

Comment: for moving it to the top, do you mean moving the state hook to the top of the code?
Moving it above the data fetching will give rise to build error as the data has not been intialized.

Comment: Hi sorry just saw your update, it says that currentInfo is undefined. I have implemented using the same method on another page and if the line

const[displayNumber] = useState(data.currentInfo.randomString)s after the last line of the swr then it is able to get the data

Comment: Yeah you need to check if all the properties are defined you can use [this](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining). ex: `useState(data?.currentInfo?.randomString)`or something like this `useState((data && data.currentInfo && data.currentInfo.randomString ) || undefined)`

Comment: Added to the answer